# java.net.Socket и объединение серверов, как клиентов

Tags: java, сервер, сокет, client

Допустим, есть три сервера написанных на Java (хотя, в целом, язык не имеет значения, но сей я пользуюсь именно Java). Главный сервер имеет возможности подключать клиентов к себе, подключаться как клиент к другим серверам и подключать другие сервера, как специальных клиентов.

Однако, к двоим (может и больше, не суть) другим серверам невозможно подключиться извне. Только они сами могут подключиться ко внешнему источнику, если будут знать как.

А вот теперь, внимание, вопрос: как связать между собой эти два сервера, чтобы они могли автономно общаться между друг другом не обращаясь к главному серверу? Если перекинуть уже готовый (серверный?клиентский) Soket через главный сервер и/или с главного сервера, возможно ли как-то их связать таким образом или я заблуждаюсь?

([En](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38724782/java-net-socket-and-connection-servers-as-clients))

Comment: А что мешает открыть новый (другой) сокет и связываться по нему?
Первый раз связались (по описанной Вами схеме - "как обычные клиенты"), далее - договорились об адресах друг-друга  номере порта для спецсвязи - и вперёд.

Comment: Проблема именно в том, что к тем двум серверам нет возможности достучаться извне (все порты по умолчанию закрыты и открывать их никто не собирается для доступа снаружи). Однако они могут подключаться к внешнему серверу. Хм. Вопрос, возможно, слегка поменялся. Возможно ли воспользоваться портами, которыми эти сервера пользуются при связи с внешним сервером? Они, ведь, являются открытыми? Или данные порты могут быть как-то хитро открытыми, что снаружи в эти порты всё равно не пролезешь? Поэксперементировать физически смогу через пару дней только, но надо подготовиться информационно.